# Proper way to configure ActionBar when using Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have many fragments inside my activity. One fragment displays Top Books and when clicking on book this fragment is replaced by fragment showing details of clicked book.

Fragment showing top books should have no title in ActionBar, but drop down navigation with categories. However fragment with details of book should have title in ActionBar.

Here comes my question: how should I handle ActionBar changes in my application. Should I configure ActionBar inside Activity or inside Fragments? If in Activity how can I handle all those changes: back button pressing, up navigation button pressing?

Please help, this situation lacks of good examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'd configure the ActionBar in the Activity.

You can override the `onBackPressed()` method to do different things depending on what fragment is showing.

This reference shows how to handle the up button being pressed, and you can change the logic depending on what fragment is showing as well: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp